# Adview errors and setting adView align using activity.java

Tags: android, google-play-services, adview

I've added adView code from google.developers to mainactivity.java, so it shows on the top of the screen. Is there any possibility to align it to the bottom using code, not xml file? 'cause when I'm trying to do it using the xml layout file, I am getting this error:

```
com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView failed to instantiate.

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 57
Exception Details:
Location:
com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.onMeasure(II)V @20: ifnull
Reason:
Expected stackmap frame at this location.
Bytecode:
0000000: 033e 0336 042a 03b6 0015 3a05 2ab6 0014
0000010: 3a06 1905 c600 2519 05b6 000b 1008 9f00
0000020: 1b2a 1905 1b1c b600 1919 05b6 000a 3e19
0000030: 05b6 0009 3604 a700 1f19 06c6 001a 2ab6
0000040: 0016 3a07 1906 1907 b600 133e 1906 1907
0000050: b600 1236 041d 2ab6 0018 b800 2a3e 1504
0000060: 2ab6 0017 b800 2a36 042a 1d1b b800 0d15
0000070: 041c b800 0db6 001a b1                 

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:363)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:190)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:778)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:517)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.reloadLayoutSwt(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1817)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.access$0(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1755)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener$1.run(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1749)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Also when I run it on my device without adView specified in layout xml file, in Logcat it shows another error, but everything seems working fine (the ad shows).

```
07-28 19:20:59.667: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(21076): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

Is there any solution for my problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how you are importing Google Play Services. I guess you have some kind of .jar, not referenced library. .jar cannot have resources packed, so it doesn't find them.
Check [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/integrating-google-play-services-on-android--cms-19828) tutorial, *"Install Play Services in your IDE"* and *"Create an Android Project"*

Comment: I've done everything step by step as was written on google.developers site.

Comment: @user3860990 have you updated it through sdk manager? Try importing them by using that tutorial.

Comment: Everything is updated, i've imported them using the tutorial, now I'm getting the same errors, but on the screen are showing two separated adViews.

Comment: are you sure you don't have old admob/google-play-services .jar library in `libs` folder, because you are now using Google Play Services?

Comment: jop, I'm sure. now it is working, but i'm getting the same errors as in my question. the add shows on the bottom as i want

Comment: did you remove the old admob stuff before trying that tutorial?

Comment: check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447822/com-google-ads-adview-failed-to-instantiate